# Python execute wsdl method with parameters

Tags: python, wsdl

I have a specific WSDL and I need to call a specific method of this WSDL using python.
The method is called "Execute" and I want these parameters and this call type

Execute(string ToolName, GPValue[] Values, GPResultOptions Options, PropertySet EnvironmentValues)

How can i call this WSDL method with this syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Why Python tag ? Do you have some code you are working on ?

Comment: I have correct my post. I need to call this wsdl method in Ptyhon

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: I have seen some different example on google but I nothing for this case

Comment: You will never learn if you don't try by yourself. There is a lot of documentation and you can't work just "looking" on google and wish to find exactly what you are looking for. SO users are not here to write code for you. If you try some code and running into troubles we will be happy to help you.

Comment: I have just try by myself using SOAPpy but is not good for my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python libraries like suds

```
from suds.client import Client

# Call to Spyne Server
client = Client('http://<client_ip>:<client_port>/?wsdl')

print(client.service.execute(toolname, etc, etc)) # Call with as many parameters you want
```